# Created folders in SSIS packages in VS 2015

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015

I have an SSIS project that I am working on with some team members. We have the project on Team Studio and expect the number of packages in it to grow massively. One of the key features we want is the ability to share data connections efficiently so it a server/ password etc changes then this is automatically brought into packages.

Is there any way to create folders within SSIS packages folders to enable us to better manage this - marked with the red arrow in the picture? Or are we approaching this in the wrong way?

[image: ssis showing where I want to create folders]